# Why is there extra space under my unordered list?

Tags: css, html-lists

With the exception of the content in the slides, I have the same slider on [this test site](http://www.test.postbourgie.com/) as a I have on [this site](http://www.postbourgie.com/), and both of these sites are running the latest WordPress installation.

For some reason, I've noticed that the `<ul class="slides"></u>` on the latter site (not the test site) has extra space at the bottom, before the clearfix. The space is not coming from the list items. The extra space is much more noticeable on mobile browsers than desktop. I don't know what is causing it, or how to get rid of it.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's becаuse you have very long title on a second last slide (Random Midday Hotness: Winter Is Coming, So Scoot A Little Closer, Baby.), which occupies two lines

You may cut a title by adding this:

```
.headline {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```